# How to store tags manually in product-filter and search app in shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am setting up a product filter through PRODUCT FILTER AND SEARCH APP in shopify but when i installed it, it only created 3 filter option such as vendor, price and product type, i also want to filter product by color and style, for that i found option in app to create new filter, i selected that and i found some options to select.
            i selected tag then i selected all tags that showed the mixture of color and style tags, i could not differentiate with the help of prefix cause in code prefix is not defined, and when i tried to manually store tags, it is not accepting, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to differentiate Color and Style tags, you need to add a specific **prefix** for each kind of tags as below:

- Color tags - `color: blue`, `color: green`, `color: light red`, etc.
- Style tags - `style: A`, `style: B`, etc.

Then, you can create a filter option by Color like this:

1. Create a filter option by Tag
2. Set “Display type” into List
3. Set “prefix” to `color:`
   [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QT0a.png)

Creating a Style one will be the same.

You can refer more information on how to work with Tags [here](https://www.notion.so/boostcommerce/How-to-create-custom-filter-options-by-Tag-7e495ab26e9a40a1a53dec3fae6e5b04)

Answer (score 0):

the PRODUCT FILTER AND SEARCH APP has recently updated its filter features, now allowing more filter options. You can now filter by any criteria: collections, size, color, tags, ratings, price, % sale off, in-stock, meta fields, and so on. Check out the new changes on [Boost Commerce's Shopify filters](https://boostcommerce.net/pages/product-filter) on the official website.